# Linked Server details cached?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to resolve a problem for a customer. They have a job which calls a stored proc on `Server A`, which calls a stored proc on `Server B`, via a linked server called `RefreshDB`. The linked server references a DNS alias, pointing to `Server B`.

Recently we migrated all the databases on `Server B` to `ServerC`. All is working fine, but when we updated the DNS alias from referencing Server B to Server C, the job on Server A started failing. Basically, the stored procedure fails saying it cannot locate `RefreshDB` in `sys.servers`. `RefreshDB` is the linked server, which does exist in `sys.servers`. It references the DNS alias.

If I ping that alias from `Server A`, I get `Server C`, which is correct. If I change the linked server to reference the actual server name, `Server C`, instead of the alias, it works. If I change the linked server to point to our test server, `Server Test`, it works. The problem is with the reference to the live server, `Server C`.

I have tried deleting `RefreshDatabases` linked server, and creating a test one called `TestLink`. `TestLink` is configured to point to `Server C`. When I try and run the job it fails saying cannot find `RefreshDatabases`! But why? I have dropped it! I even used `sp_dropservers 'RefreshDatabases'`.

If I update `TestLink` to point to another server, it works. It's just when we reference `Server A` that we get a failure referencing `RefreshDatabases`. There is some sort of cached setting that is causing problems here, but I just don't know where! Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure you migrated all the security properly when migrating Server B objects over to Server C?  This sounds like the account you are using to establish connectivity over the Linked Server may not have sufficient permissions on Server C to execute the SP.  Also, confirm that the `RPC Out` server option is enabled on the RefreshDB Linked Sever on Server A.  During the dropping/recreating of your linked servers, this option may have been left at its default, which is `False` and disallows remote SP calls.

Comment: @doodling-dba did you ever figure out what happened there?  We're about to replace a bunch of linked server with CNAMEs, so I'm curious about both your problem, and whether we need to bounce boxes afterwards, etc. Thanks.